# How to do Like search in SOLR for hierarchy condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solr, hierarchy, solrnet

In SQL Server we did `where HierarchyKey like '%~' + cast(id as varchar) + '~%'` when joining to a hierarchy table so that we could roll up hierarchical results for categories within categories.

Is it possible to do the same type of comparison with Solr? If not, what other reasonable solutions are there to this problem that don't require me to totally redesign the way we do hierarchies?

Comment: Do you have a proper example of what you're indexing and what your query looks like - and what you expect to match and not match? Solr has a [PathHierarchyTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer) that is usually used for working with hierarchies.

Comment: @MatsLindh We have training courses that belong to one or more categories, which may be the subcategory of another category. The hierarchy key for a category may look like this: `~2781~1432~4341~`. So that category is 4341 which is child of 1432 which is child of 2781. I think there is probably a good solution with the PathHierarchyTokenizer you mentioned, though at the moment I'm leaning toward a very simple solution of just creating 3 columns for L1, L2, and L3 category as we only have the 3 levels and a given category is only ever represented at one of the levels.